# Sorting script and pagination failed

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

Hi guys i am trying to use one Sorting script 
http://www.hawkee.com/snippet/4189/
Script is great its works without click GO or submit he had java, but when the story come to pagination its broken ;\ its reset to `$orderby = $_GET[orderby];
if(!$orderby) { $orderby = 'price_asc'; }` and the pagination continue to asc not desc or any other value u put :(
Any idea how should this might gona to work with pagination ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you think it would be helpful to add your `orderby` data to the pagination links?

This should work:

```
"<a href=\"?page=" . $i . ($_GET['orderby'] ? ('&orderby=' .  $_GET['orderby']) : '') . "\">" . $i . "</a>";
```

Comment: Wrong is that when i sort by desc or asc ;\ its good for the 1st page , but when i use pagination for other page's its reset it to the 1st in the case price_asc ;\ code for pagination doesnt remember the Sort section

Comment: and how to add $_GET into this:
echo "<a href=\"?page=$next\"><font face=\"Trebuchet MS\">Next</font></a> ";

Comment: "<a href=\"?page=" . $next . ($_GET['orderby'] ? ('&orderby=' .  $_GET['orderby']) : '') . "\"><font face=\"Trebuchet MS\">Next</font></a> ";

Comment: Basic knowledge of PHP syntax would be very helpful. I suggest to use single quotes for PHP strings.